# Where is the visualVM executable for linux?

Tags: linux, installation, eclipse, plugins

I'm trying to install the VisualVM plugin for eclipse, on my Ubuntu linux.

I'm following the [instructions here](http://visualvm.java.net/eclipse-launcher.html).

So I've done the installation part, and the plugin is installed to eclipse.

Now for the configation, I need to enter the path to the executable.

Any idea of where this would be?

I've looked at /bin/ there's no file named visualvm or anything similar. And there's just jar files in the extracted download.

Comment: Where did you [install VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/download.html#first_steps)?

Comment: I used the eclipse 'install software' option and pointed it at the extracted folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just installing the launcher doesn't actually [install VisualVM](https://web.archive.org/web/20120618043557/http://visualvm.java.net/download.html). They are separate products.

Comment: It would be interesting to have the real answer to the question ... where is the exec?

Comment: ***visualvm\bin\visualvm.exe*** or ***visualvm/bin/visualvm*** depending on your operating system

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the jdk installed.

On ubuntu, and probably other too the binary will be:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jvisualvm
```

You have to adapt the version of course

Answer (score 2):

Three steps into terminal:

1. `sudo apt update`
2. `sudo apt install visualvm`
3. `visualvm

After that, you need to accept the Oracle license:

[image]

The the result you will see:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using the find command, like so, or similar.

```
sudo find / -exec grep "*visualvm*" {} \; -print
```

Also, look in /usr/bin, /usr/lib, and even ~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins.

I don't use Eclipse myself, but I have a distant memory from when I did.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: Currently, if the VisualVM path is missing, starting a run of your code with the VisualVM launcher will show:

> An internal error occurred during: "Launching [main class]". **java.lang.NullPointerException**

To fix this, go to: Properties->Run/Debug->Launching->VisualVM Configuration and fill in the "VisualVM Executable" box with the correct path.

The executable path will be `[path into folder where you extracted contents of your VisualVM download]\bin\visualvm.exe` or `.../bin/visualvm`, depending on your OS (as Sha commented).

**If you cannot find this path in your system, it's likely because you've only installed the VisualVM Launcher, but not the VisualVM itself** (as M.Hampton mentioned).

You can get VisualVM from here: http://visualvm.java.net/download.html#first_steps
(don't click the Eclipse IDE integration 'cause that's just gonna take you to the launcher again).